# how to change android Api version in processing

Tags: processing

I am writing a program with processing.I have problem installing android with API 10,

How can I change Android API version in Processing from 10 to 19 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `sdkVersion` in the `AndroidBuild.java` (currently line 48, see [here](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/blob/master/src/processing/mode/android/AndroidBuild.java)) in the [source](https://github.com/processing/processing-android) and finally re-build by running [ant](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/ant/).

```
class AndroidBuild extends JavaBuild {

  //  static final String basePackage = "changethispackage.beforesubmitting.tothemarket";
  static final String basePackage = "processing.test";
  static String sdkName = "2.3.3";
  static String sdkVersion = "10";  // Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread)
  static String sdkTarget = "android-" + sdkVersion; 
  //...
```